# How do droids determine chances?

Tags: star-wars, droids, rogue-one

I've noticed that many droids in the Star Wars universe--specifically K-2SO and C-3PO--say a lot of things about chances of arbitrary things happening, like "Sir, the possibility of successfully navigating an asteroid field is approximately 3,720 to 1," or "You have a 97.6 percent chance of failure."  I noticed while watching Rogue One hat some of these chances seem really hard to calculate, like whatever K-2SO said about Jyn betraying Cassian.  How exactly are these chances determined?

Comment: How do Vulcans calculate odds?

Comment: Statistical analysis is a speciality of droids

Comment: @CHEESE  -  nailed it!

Comment: That's just a scriptwriterese way of saying the odds are against the heroes. **We all know that 43.7% of all statistics are made up on the spot.**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The new Rogue One novelisation indicates that droids determine statistical probabilities by performing "*mental simulations*" of likely outcomes.

> *With one second left until total shutdown, K-2SO chose to mentally
> simulate an impossible scenario in which Cassian Andor escaped alive.*
>
> *The simulation pleased him.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Rogue One: A Star Wars Story - Official Novelisation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Rogue_One:_A_Star_Wars_Story_(novel))</sup></sub>